# Не получается по созданному ограничению ON DELETE CASCADE удалить данные из двух таблиц

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: есть у меня следующие таблицы
[image: Таблица с песнями]

и

[image: Таблица с текстами песен]

Для реализации удаления по ограничению использовал:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Songs ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Songs_Texts 
FOREIGN KEY (Text_ID) REFERENCES dbo.Texts(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Стоит учесть, что при добавлении песни в БД, в поле `Text_ID` кладётся `NULL`. Текст может добавляться только при изменении информации о песне. В `Song_Title` хранится `ID` песни. Когда произвожу удаление песни, запись о песне из таблицы Songs удаляется, а текст из таблицы `Texts` не удаляется. Может быть следует изменить ограничение от `Songs.ID`  к `Texts.Song_Title`? Или всё же можно что-то сделать с первоначальным вариантом?

Comment: По моему, вы FK не в ту сторону делаете. У вас будет удаляться песня при удалении текста. Насколько я понимаю, вы хотите наоборот. Тогда вам нужен внешний ключ в таблице `Texts` ссылающийся на таблицу `Songs`

Comment: я бы сказал, что, очевидно, нужно изменить  на `songs.id -> texts.song_title` попутно переименовав последнее в `song_id`

Comment: @teran да, это я как раз и имел в виду. Сейчас попробую накинуть через song_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По совету [@teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran) сделал ограничение по Songs.ID -> Texts.Song_ID и всё заработало!

P.S. запрос, изменяющий имя столбца `EXEC sp_RENAME 'dbo.Texts.Song_Title', 'Song_ID', 'COLUMN'`